# Serial connection to sun blade 6000 chassis

Tags: solaris

This ones a bit embarrassing.  :-P

Ok, I've got the right cable (it works with our other sun machines - it's a blue cisco cable serial db9 to rj45) connected from a laptop running solaris to the management port on the sunblade 6000 chassis.  From the console of the laptop, "tip 9600 /dev/ttya" gets me a "connected".

Is there a magic key combination to get into the ilom?

I've tried .~ .# ~. #. pressing enter a bunch of times, etc.

Can anyone put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man...

Have you tried `ESC-B`?

Comment: Thanks for answering :-P  I had forgotten about "tip hardwire" that worked fine without any magic key sequence.  :-P  +1 for being the only answer

Comment: Ack, I can't +1 because I don't have 15 rep yet